# Prove that set of increasing polynomials of degree $n$ is a connected subset of the set of all polynomials of degree $n.$

Tags: general-topology, derivatives, polynomials, connectedness

> Let $X$ be the space of all real polynomials $a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + \cdots + a_n t^n$ of degree at most $n.$ We may think of $X$ as a topological space via it's identification with $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ given by $$a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2 + \cdots + a_n t^n \longmapsto (a_0,a_1,a_2, \cdots , a_n).$$ Now consider the space $S$ consisting of all polynomials in $X$ that are increasing (as a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$). Is $S$ a connected subset of $X\ $?

$\textbf{My Thoughts} :$ If $f(t) \in S$ then $f'(t) \gt 0,$ for all $t \in \Bbb R.$ Now for each fixed $t \in \Bbb R$ the equation $f'(t) = 0$ determines a plane passing through the origin in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ and thus it's complement will have two connected components. How to determine the connected components in terms of $f\ $? I think one of them is determined by $f'(t) \gt 0$ and the other one is determined by $f'(t) \lt 0.$ Although I am struggling to prove this. With these things in mind what can we conclude about the connectedness of $S\ $? I got stuck at this stage. Any help will be highly solicited.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it convex, and therefore connected?

If $f$ and $g$ are increasing polynomials, can't you prove that $\alpha f+(1-\alpha) g$ is also increasing, for any $\apha\in[0,1]$?

This would show that the space is convex, or even better, path-connected. Don't either of these imply it's connected?

Comment: Yes @Michael Hartley I get your point. Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: If you were to continue the method shown in your question, note that $f \in S$ if and only if $f'(t) \geq 0$ for all $t$ and $f'\neq 0$.  In other words, you'd need to project the whole space down one dimension (forgetting the constant coefficient), intersect a bunch of closed half-planes and show in this smaller space that you can remove the origin.  The pull it back to the larger space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got lucky and this seems to work:

If $P$ and $Q$ are increasing polynomial then $aP+(1-a)Q$ is also an increasing polynomial for all $a\in [0,1]$.

It follows that our set is path connected, because the path $f:[0,1] \rightarrow S$ given by $f(a) = aP+(1-a)Q$ is a path.

I guess this means that the idea you had doesn't really work.

Comment: Oh! Great. Very nice idea. Many many thanks. Would you please explain which of my idea fails to work? Thanks again.

Comment: glad to have been able to help, I also tried doing stuff similar to what you were doing but then I realized this works which made it immediate.